# ASP.NET MVC: The view 'Login' or its master could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6

I am attempting to deploy my ASP.NET MVC application to a new environment and I'm running into this error:

```
The view 'Login' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/Login.aspx
~/Views/Account/Login.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
```

I have verified that ~/Views/Account/Login.aspx exists.

The server is Windows 2k3 running IIS 6.  We are not using wildcard mapping, but rather file extensions.  This very same version of the site runs fine in 2 other environments, both that have similar setup (2k3 and IIS 6).

Could this be a permissions issue or something?

Comment: Is "~/Vies/Account/Login.aspx" a typo or is the Views directory really misnamed?  I'm assuming typo, but just to be sure...

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, sorry.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fool.  My master page wasn't copied out to the new server.  Once there, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that MS change LogIn for LogOn (notice the O) in RC1.

Answer (score 0):

Check consistency.

If the file ~/Views/Account/Login.aspx exists, check that the controller there exists an action named Login in the controller Account.

Also you could rebuild and re-deploy your application.